# Is declaring a string literal with a pointer more memory efficient than declaring constant array?

Tags: c, pointers

If I want to store a constant string,

```
const char array[] = "Some string literal.";
```

The C primer plus book says

> then the quoted string is stored in a data segment that is part of the executable file. Memory for the array is allocated only after the program begins running. At that time, the quoted string is copied into the array.

Does this mean memory is allocated twice for the string literal?

On the other hand when declared with pointer, it only sets aside the storage for the pointer variable and stores the address of string literal into it.

```
const char *pt = "Some string literal.";
```

Which means there is only one copy of the string literal and declaring pointer with string literal is more memory efficient than array?

Comment: The "C primer plus book" (whatever that is) is making untrue generalisations about how compilers work - presumably on the basis of how ONE compiler happens to work.   The standard states no requirements on how these constructs are reflected in an executable file, and different compilers do different things (at least, in part, because different executable formats allow things to be done differently).

Comment: The "efficiency" of the alternatives should be of no concern to you. These will never be bottlenecks of any magnitude; if your question is not entirely of academic nature, you fell into the trap of premature optimization.

Comment: @Peter-- I don't think that it is helpful to undermine someone's faith in the book they are learning from if you don't know the book. _C Primer Plus_  is in its 6th ed., and I have found it not perfect, but very good. We don't know OP's edition, but in mine it is first said that "character string constants are placed in the _static storage_ class," and then later that "typically... the quoted string is stored in a data segment...." I wouldn't call this an untrue generalisation, but you may reasonably disagree.

Comment: It all depends on the implementation details. You could inspect what happens on the implementation you normally use. Also it makes a difference whether this code is at block scope or file scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case the data for the string is stored in the executable file, and it's stored in memory once the program is loaded. So yes it is "allocated twice" but in very different storage mediums (disk and memory).

However, the same is true for the second case as well. The string literal needs to be stored once in the executable file on disk, and once in memory when the program is running.

The difference is an implementation detail, namely that in the first case the string in memory is stored either on the stack or in some global modifiable data memory segment. In the second case the string is usually stored together with the code.

So if you only have one instance of the string in the first case, there is no difference in "memory efficiency".

Comment: How can the first string be modified? `array` is declared as `const char`

Comment: @babon Oops, missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on whether the definition appears at global or local scope.

- At global scope:

  - The first option defines an initialized constant array. Reading bytes from it with `array[0]` will result in code that reads single bytes from a global memory location, usually a single instruction.
  - The second option defines a modifiable pointer initialized to point to a constant array of characters.  Reading bytes from it with `array[0]` will result in code that loads the pointer value and reads the element pointed by the pointer, usually at least 2 instructions.

  If you do not need to change the string `array` refers to, it would probably be preferable to use the first option.
- At local scope (automatic storage)

  - The first option defines an array initialized with a string.  If this array was not constant and was modified inside the function, the code generated would be substantially similar to this:

    ```
    char array[sizeof "Some string literal."];
    memcpy(array, "Some string literal.", sizeof(array));
    ```

    But since it is defined as `const`, the compile could optimize the code and generate references to `array` as references to the string literal in static storage. To avoid potential code generation such as the above, you could use this definition at local scope:

    ```
    static const char array[] = "Some string literal.";
    ```
  - Conversely, the second option defines a local pointer initialized to point to a string literal, itself most likely stored in static storage such as a data segment or even the code segment.  Provided the function uses `array`, the definition could generate a store to initalize the pointer and more or less code to read characters from it depending on the specific code inside the function and how efficient the compiler is.

At global scope it seems more efficient to use the first approach.

At local scope, it depends a lot on the actual code and compiler used, but defining a `static const char` array might be the most efficient.

Comment: There are significant differences between how compilers handle function local string constants.  Some will store it outside the function in constant data while others may even use integer constants in the instructions to hold small strings in registers.